# Paypal e-mail address in paypal button

Tags: html, paypal

I am creating a web site and having a paypal checkout button. The site is made in PHP. I found  this paypal code in paypal's web site.

```
<form name="_xclick" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="HTML book">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="24.99">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
</form>
```

Is `<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">` referring to the PayPal e-mail address where the amount will be credited after the checkout is successful?

Also is there a way I can test this button without actually paying through paypal?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that email address is the recipient. Most people, however, would use their PayPal Business ID instead, so as not to have their email address publicly posted where spambots can see it.

As for testing a button, if clicking it takes you to the correct checkout page, you can test everything up to the final "send money" button without actually paying anything. You can also use the PayPal Sandbox for testing things like IPN.

Comment: Thanks.. Will spam bots be able to see my e-mail address if I pull it from a database and write the above within my PHP script?

Comment: Yes, because it'll still be there in the HTML. The bot doesn't care where the email address is stored on the server, all its grubby eyes need to see is that something vaguely looks like an email address in the HTML.

Comment: just curious.. will introducing a capcha prevent bots from reading my e-mail address. What I mean is the paypal button on my web site won't be enabled until the captcha entered is correct.

Comment: Maybe, but it's just so much easier to use the business ID.